# Localhost just stopped working

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I use xampp as hosting server software.

Everything been worked since I installed the software for the first time I also updated xampp regular when there was a better version.

But three days ago so it was a power cut at night and when I started up my computer the day after, I can not access my localhost neither 127.0.0.1 or http://localhost/ also tested with my http://192.168.0.101/ but neither one of them allows me to access my localhost.

I've looked through some forums where a similar issue come up and have tested some solutions that have worked for others.

My hosts file looks like it should do, so have no ideas on what could be the cause of this problem.

Would be really grateful if someone could solve it for me or give me some sort of advice on a solution.

Thanks for your time. 
Yours Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Server may have stopped and you may need to start it manually:

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1173

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#378

Answer (score 0):

Check the apache service is running properly or not
if apache service is running still it is not working then change the service port of apache from 80 to some other port. Then restart the apache and in browser open http://localhost:[port]
In port specify the port no which you have change changed in apache configuration file.

Also check the entry in c:\windows\system32\etc\hosts

This is how you can solve your problems.
If still problem persist then post in detail here only as answer. and also specify your working platform.

Comment: if still problem persist then reinstall your webserver

Comment: Tryed that allredy but I just looked at the apache error log i got an error about if IPV6 is enable.

Answer (score 0):

it might be that Apache and mySQL stop. (in xampp)
to see if that's why,In the directory on the computer where XAMPP is installed, click the file:xampp-control.exe
And click Start: Apache and mySQL.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HWQs.png)